# Why are there "undefined" terms where the outputs are supposed to go to?

Tags: javascript

The output should look like "Tuesday, July 26, 2016", and then "enjoy" But instead, it looks like 
"Tuesday
July
undefined,undefined 26 , 2016
Tuesday"

Here is my code: 
var today = new Date();

```
function getMonth1(today) {
    if(today.getMonth() == 0) {
        console.log("January");
    }
    else if(today.getMonth() == 1) {
        console.log("February");
    }
    else if(today.getMonth() == 2) {
        console.log("March");
    }
    else if(today.getMonth() == 3) {
        console.log("April");
    }
    else if(today.getMonth() == 4) {
        console.log("May");
    }
    else if(today.getMonth() == 5) {
        console.log("June");
    }
    else if(today.getMonth() == 6) {
        console.log("July");
    }
    else if(today.getMonth() == 7) {
        console.log("August");
    }
    else if(today.getMonth() == 8) {
        console.log("September");
    }
    else if(today.getMonth() == 9) {
        console.log("October");
    }
    else if(today.getMonth() == 10) {
        console.log("November");
    }
    else if(today.getMonth() == 11) {
        console.log("December");
    }
}

function getWeekday(today) {
    if(today.getDay() == 0) {
        console.log("Sunday");
    }
    else if(today.getDay() == 1)    {
        console.log("Monday");
    }
    else if(today.getDay() == 2)    {
        console.log("Tuesday");
    }
    else if(today.getDay() == 3)    {
        console.log("Wednesday");
    }
    else if(today.getDay() == 4)    {
        console.log("Thursday");
    }
    else if(today.getDay() == 5)    {
        console.log("Friday");
    }
    else if(today.getDay() == 6)    {
        console.log("Saturday");
    }
}


function getDate1(today) {
    console.log(getWeekday(today) + "," + getMonth1(today), today.getDate(), ",", today.getFullYear());
    if(getWeekday(today) == "Tuesday") { 
        console.log("enjoy");
     }
    }
```

getDate1(today);

Comment: functions getMonth1 and getWeekDay return undefined - instead of `console.log` in those functions, you need to `return` a value ... you should see that the output currently is over three lines, not one, as you have suggested in your question

Comment: So are you saying that I should replace all the "console.log" in the getMonth1 and getWeekday function to "return"?

Comment: that is exactly what I said

Comment: Please, for the love of god, use switch statements

Comment: Not switch statements. Just array lookups would do fine here.

Comment: I would highly recommend to use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/). With that, you can replace your code with just a single line.

Answer (score 0):

As well as having to return a value as Jaromanda X mentions, you could streamline your code a great deal like this (an array lookup, as Touffy mentions):

```
function getWeekDay(index) {
    return 
    ["Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"][index];
}
```

Then use `getDay()` to call it:

```
alert(getWeekDay(new Date().getDay()));
```

Then do the analogous setup for the months, using `getMonth()` to call it.